# windows batch script split run_dt=1/3/2015 by "/"

Tags: windows, batch-file

on condition sucess I am trying to split the date by "/" and concat again as 01032015. The following code is working, but when I keep this in the if condition, this fails.

```
set date_only=%dateparam:*dt= =%
echo %date_only%

REM above line prevents unexpected results when input string has less than two /

set mm=%date_only:*/=%
echo !mm!
set yyyy=%mm:*/=%
echo !yyyy!
set dd=!date_only:/%mm%=!
echo !dd!
set dd=!dd:~3,2!
echo !dd!
set mm=!mm:/%yyyy%=!
echo !mm!
set yyyy=!yyyy:~0,4!

echo.%dd%
echo.%mm%
echo.%yyyy%
```

with if condition the above same is changing to follows

```
if "%isDateFound%" == "true" (
echo %isDateFound%

set date_only=%dateparam:*dt= =%
    echo !date_only!
set mm=!!date_only:*/=!
echo month 
echo !mm!
set yyyy=!!mm:*/=!
echo year
echo !yyyy!
set dd=!!date_only:/!mm!=!!
echo date
echo !dd!
set dd=!dd:~3,2!
set mm=!!mm:/%yyyy%=!
set yyyy=!yyyy:~0,4!
echo !dd!
echo !mm!
echo !yyyy!
)
```

looks like because of the delayedexpression the statements like set dd=!!date_only:/!mm!=!! are not working. How to get refer the variables inside the if conditions.

if there any better way to get dd mm yyyy ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "dateparm=run_dt=1/3/2015"
SET "isdatefound=true"
IF "%isdatefound%"=="true" (
 FOR /f "tokens=2,3,4delims==/" %%a IN ("%dateparm%") DO (
  SET /a dd=100+%%a
  SET /a mm=100+%%b
  SET /a yyyy=%%c
 )
 SET "dd=!dd:~-2!"
 SET "mm=!mm:~-2!"
 SET "ddmmyyyy=!dd!!mm!!yyyy!"
 REM echos to prove
 ECHO day    dd=!dd!
 ECHO month  mm=!mm!
 ECHO year   yyyy=!yyyy!
 ECHO concat ddmmyyyy=!ddmmyyyy!
)

GOTO :EOF
```

It's difficult to tell whether your format is dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy. It appears that the string `run_dt=1/3/2015` is contained in `dateparm`.

So - if the condition is true, tokenise the string using `=` and `/` as separators, use tokens 2,3 and 4 assigned to `%%a` and implicitly `%%b` and `%%c`.

Add 100 to each of month and day. then take the last 2 characters of each. `!var!` used because we need the run-time value of variables.

Concatenate the variables to `ddmmyyyy` then show the results.

Naturally, you'd need to switch `dd` and `mm` throughout if you mean to use `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way :

```
@echo off
set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
echo hour=%hour%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
echo min=%min%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%
echo secs=%secs%

set year=%date:~-4%
echo year=%year%
set month=%date:~3,2%
if "%month:~0,1%" == " " set month=0%month:~1,1%
echo month=%month%
set day=%date:~0,2%
if "%day:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%
echo day=%day%
Set MaDate=%day%/%month%/%year%
Set MyTime=%hour%:%min%:%secs%
echo %MaDate%
echo %MyTime%
set DateTimeFile=%year%_%month%_%day%_%hour%_%min%_%secs%.log
echo DateTimeFile=%DateTimeFile%
pause
```

Or i got another solution from **foxidrive** :

```
::From foxidrive
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo stamp: "%stamp%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You have *not* described what is the format of `%date_only%` variable, so I assumed it is DD/MM/YYYY. This should work:

```
if "%isDateFound%" == "true" (
   echo %isDateFound%

   set date_only=%dateparam:*dt= =%
   echo !date_only!

   for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("!date_only!") do (
      set "dd=%%a"
      set "mm=%%b"
      set "yyyy=%%c"
   )

   echo !dd!
   echo !mm!
   echo !yyyy!
)
```

If there is a point in your problem that this code does not cover, please *describe it*!

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is using `WMIC` :

Here is a better way to do that :

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%a IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year ^| findstr [0-9]') DO (
    set "$Day=0%%a"
    set "$Month=0%%b"
    set "$Year=%%c"
 )

echo %$Year%%$Month:~-2%%$Day:~-2%
```

The leading 0 before before Month and Day is automatically added.